# angular-ui Calendar populated twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using the [Angular-UI calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) to display some events. I have an activity controller which makes a call to backend service. Once I get the data, I bind it to the model.

```
//activity controller
    $scope.events = [];
    Activities.get()
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.activities = data;
                    populateEvents();
                });

            function populateEvents() {
                $scope.activities.forEach(function(a) {
                    $scope.events.push({title: a.name, start: a.date, url: a.url});
                });
            }

            $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

//index.html
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

When I load the calendar for the first time, two copies of the event are displayed. Not sure if I am doing it the correct way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading two versions of Angular on your site. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/aO1LZqWiZAK5LZ0EJNn4?p=preview

Comment: still duplicates the events for some reason..
If I change month and come back, then I see one copy but on the first load I always see 2 copies for events in the current month.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in a project and our solution was in the eventSource initialization. 
We put an object inside the array and, magically, it worked.

```
$scope.events = [{}];
```

I had no explanation about why, but it did the trick!